# Taleo OBIEE - Merged Candidate Profiles Showing

Tags: obiee, taleo

I have created a report in `Taleo OBIEE` and I am getting a result that is not correct and I am trying to mask out the incorrect data (or determine what has been done incorrectly to cause this). I have merged candidates showing on the report.  I these cases the following is what has happened:

1. A recruiter has merged profile `A` into profile `B`
2. Profile B is then matched to a requisition and the candidate is hired
3. I run a query to find candidates tied to filled requisitions who have not been dis positioned so these can be taken care of

When I run the report, along with the legitimate results I am getting a row with profile A which has been merged into `B` already.  Since the candidate was hired with profile `B` and `A` is merged into it I would not expect to be seeing anything ties to profile `A`.

I have attempted to resolve by looking at the candidate event tied to the merge, but both the `A` and `B` profiles have the merge event listed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the profiles were merged, the old profile `A` was soft deleted and was still accessible at the database level.  In OBI Reporting you can mask out these records as follows: Candidate > Candidate Identification > Record Status, with values of AVAILABLE or STORED, and STORED being the soft deleted record.